# Storing images and files in iOS devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, image

I would like to know about storing the images or files of my application to the device. I think we can store these things to Document directory/library. I would like to know , is there any other options we have.

I have seen somewhere like, we can save the images to photo library with UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum.Could anyone please give me more information regarding this.If it is saved to photo library where is it being saved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can save to the local user directory for the app, though keep in mind that this is sandboxed by iOS so that each app has its own document directory.

For example, here is code (Swift 3) to get a "Database Working Folder":

```
// The working folder for our DB. This will be in the user's document store!
var _dbWorkingFolder: String?
// We're just going to use the user's document folder
_dbWorkingFolder = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
```

It is possible to use AppGroups to have 2
or more apps that you control share a single space. But keep in mind this AppGroup has to be engineered into all apps that use it!

Here is [Apple's doc on the iOS file system](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW12)

Here is [Apple's doc on writing App Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html) which actually uses AppGroups to allow an extension and and App to share space.

Finally, yes there is full support for you to write to the Photo Library. You'll want to use the Photos Framework and the images and videos are simply saved into the iOS "Photos" app. You can create a folder to hold your App's images, for instance.

Here is a link to [Apple's Photos Framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos).

If you have more specific questions, be sure to post those along with code you've tried and you'll get lots of help here!

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response :) Shall I ask you one more doubt as I am having so much confusions about storage of assets.When we use sqlite , file with  .db extension can only be stored in Documents directory or we have some other options including library?

Comment: Sure. Happy to help. Have done work with all of this so it's fresh in my mind. However, would you accept my answer or at lest up-vote it?

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Could you please check my first comment and reply on it?

Comment: Sure, your SQLite .db file can be stored on either the local app document directory OR the AppGroup. It is easier to store in the local App home directory, and if you don't have 2 or more apps that need to share the data, you really don't want to bother with AppGroups.

Comment: I just added code of how you can "fetch" the path to the user's "Document Directory". See my edited answer above.